# Frangi filter working as an edge detector

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, imagefilter

I was trying to extract all the stems from a plant image using Frangi filter. I wanted to make use of the property that each stem has more vessel like characteristics than a leaf. [Using this paper as reference](http://www.araa.asn.au/acra/acra2013/papers/pap171s1-file1.pdf).

My input image is this

[image]

And this is my matlab code snippet

```
 options=struct('FrangiScaleRange', [1 3], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 1, 'FrangiBetaOne', 0.5,...
       'FrangiBetaTwo', 2, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
      [outIm,whatScale,Direction] = FrangiFilter2D(double(rgb2gray(img2)), options);
      outIm = uint8(outIm/max(outIm(:))*256);
```

This is the output

[image]

I am aware that there could be other ways to accomplish this task but i am just curious to know, why this approach is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? To me, the filter seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: It is supposed to be detecting vessel like structures, which in this case should be stems alone. But the filter seems to be working somewhat like an edge detector by highlighting the leaves too. @dasdingonesin

Comment: Did you actually read the paper? The algorithm to detect the stems has 8 steps. The Frangi filter is only the first step. Judging from the filtered image, you also need find better filter parameters to get satisfactory results.

Comment: I did read the paper. If you see the step by step results. You will see that the output at the end on 1st step is no where close to the one i am getting. I have tried playing around with the parameters but cant seem to emulate the results shown in the paper. I have even tried using the exact same parameters as the paper. But the output image with mentioned parameters is hardly recognisable.@dasdingonesin

Comment: I think as far as the filter is concerned those are vessels.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the parameters i am choosing ? @dasdingonesin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of Frangi-filter, both your stems and leafs are vessel-like as discussed already, so you cannot simply use the filter output to distinguish between them.

What you can however, is: (i) choose better scales ( roughly fitted to the scale of a structure you are trying to detect) and (ii) try different parameters.

I had a try, given scales `5 10 20 30` and Frangi parameters `beta=0.5` and `c=100`

[image: Frangi eq.]

[Frangi et al.: Multiscale vessel enhancement filtering, MICCAI 1998]

this is what I got:

[image: Frangi]

Scales in logical units of the original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6wuE.jpg, which was converted to gray-8bpp in Photoshop.

What you can observe is the following. Leafs give response at higher scales than stems. Maybe that could be a clue.

EDIT:

I had a look at the https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZwxg.png. The "edge detector"-effect on bright leafs is due to fact that the Frangi's theory fits insufficiently to two dimensions:

- 3-D vessel: small eigenvalue in vessel direction, two highly negative eigenvalues in the other two orthogonal directions.
- 2-D vessel: small eigenvalue in vessel direction, one highly negative eigenvalue perpendicular to it.

and in contrary

- 3-D plate: one highly negative eigenvalue, two small ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and i agree that these leaves can be treated as vessels too by the filter. But if you could check out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971579/detect-all-branches-in-a-plant-picture. Here the leaves are clearly blob like and stems vessel like, The filter still acts somewhat like an edge detector. If you could check the picture specified in the link and give an explanation. I would be happy to accept this answer of yours.Much appreciated @mainactual

Comment: And where are you implementing your Frangi filter. Because i am struggling to emulate these results with the given parameters in matlab. @mainactual

Comment: Thank you for your insights. They are really helpful. I am gladly accepting your answer. It would be great if you could share the results you got on this image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/eZwxg.png.

Comment: @HARJATINSINGH, have a look at http://i.imgur.com/fe5iXr0.png scales `1.5 2 3` (~radii of stems), `beta=0.5`, `c=50`.

Answer (score 0):

The Frangi filter measures how elongated an image region is, so it detects vessels as objects that are "long" and not "blobby".  The example image in the paper has stems that are narrow and straight (like yours) and leaves that are quite round (unlike yours).  Because the leaves are longer and skinnier than in the paper, the algorithms at the first step is working less well.  Your options are:

(a) futz with the parameters (in matlab, I believe they are the FrangiAlpha, and  .FrangiBeta parameters).  Those are set to 0.5 by default, I think you need to set them lower (so that you have to be even longer and skinnier to be counted as a stem).

(b) like @dasdingonesin said, the paper has many steps, and the Hough Filter step later will also encourage long continuous lines at a bigger scale than the Frangi filter considers.

Comment: If you could explain the failure of Frangi filter in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971579/detect-all-branches-in-a-plant-picture
I would be happy to accept your answer.